# How to make graphic more or less detailed depending on zoom-level (similar to how Google Maps works)?

Tags: pdf, charts, zoom, svg, smart-response

Not sure if this is the right site to ask this question. If not, maybe some admin can move it?

Are there some file formats (Or is this a software thing?), such as SVG or PDF, that supports reducing/increasing the level of detail depending on the zoom level?

I am creating a historical timeline that is gonna be very big and with **a lot** of information. I would like that if you looked at it in whole, the level of detail should be reduced so the gaps where nothing happened are easy to see, while if you look at just a small part of it, all information, including large chunks of text, should be visible.

Of course, it should be "smart" so that only elements that don't block other elements appear when you zoom.

---

I realise that an alternative approach would be a "dynamic magnifying glass", like this function in the Preview application in MacOS:

[image]

Comment: SVG is most likely to be able to store e.g. "zoomlevel" data (specifiying details to draw when zoomed in that far), but then you need an application that actually uses it intelligently - I'm not aware of any such application.

Comment: @KJ In my specific case the graphics is quite simple, it is just very long horizontally. It is useful to zoom out to see the overall pattern, without clutter, but it would also be useful to zoom in and see the specific details.